# What does this Clojurescript cljs-http error mean?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In order to validate a captcha in Clojurescript I'm using cljs-http like this:

```
(def verify-url "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify")
;...
(http/post verify-url {:json-params {:secret key :response captcha-data}})
;...
```

...and the result is is:

> {:status 0,
>    :success false,
>    :body "",
>    :headers {},
>    :trace-redirects ["https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
>                      "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"],
>    :error-code :http-error,
>    :error-text " [0]"}

What does this mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your preflight (OPTIONS) requiest gets failed. Check your Developer Console for something like:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3449' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.